# словосочетание "Белопероне капельнАЯ"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Почему в справочной литературе используется словосочетание "Белопероне капельнАЯ"?. Если у прилагательного окончание - АЯ, то и существительное должно быть женского рода. Существительные женского рода имеют окончания - а, -я, - ь после шипящих. Окончание -е имеют существительные среднего рода и иностранные слова мужского рода с нулевым окончанием могут иметь в конце -е, которое входит в корень слова( например кофе). Тогда правильно, либо - белопероне капельнОЕ, либо - белопероне капельнЫЙ, либо - белоперон(А, Я) - капельная. Понятно, что в иностранном языке - это слово скорее всего женского рода, но найдите мне хоть одно слово в русском языке женского рода с буквой Е в конце слова. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Белопероне – это название рода, капельная – название вида.

Это обычное сложное наименование растений: сначала указывается род, а потом вид. Всего **род Белопероне** насчитывает от 30 до 60 видов, которые распространены в тропических и субтропических регионах Америки.

Соответственно, здесь **не действуют обычные правила определения грамматического рода по окончанию слова,** женский род для этого вида растений определяется исходя и**з других факторов**. У этого растения есть другие названия, которые относятся к  женскому роду.

**Белопероне капельная** (Beloperone guttata) – основной вид, который выращивается в домашних условиях. Родиной растения является Мексика, поэтому зачастую его еще называют ***Мексиканская красавица***.Существует еще одно название — ***Юстиция Брандега.***

Впервые **она появилась** на цветочной выставке в Ганновере в 1932 году, не оставив равнодушным ни одного цветовода.

Чтобы **белопероне росла** компактным кустом и обильно цвела, ежегодно ранней весной обрезайте побеги на половину длины и удаляйте несколько первых цветков.

https://garden.wikireading.ru/16052

https://chvetochki.ru/beloperone/

О других названиях растения:

https://www.botanichka.ru/article/pestryie-i-pyishnyie-yustitsii/